# Windows 8.1 requires elevated rights for common tasks

Tags: windows-8.1, administrator, privileges, runas, msysgit

I've moved from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 (fresh install, different machines) and I'm having some issues with user permissions on my Windows 8.1 machine.

It seems to require Administrator rights for even the most basic tasks such as running `git pull` in the msysGit shell or using SourceTree's GUI for discarding changed but uncommited files. If I start either of the two projects with "Run as Admin", they work. On Windows 7 this wasn't required.

It's not just Git-related things that fail unless ran with admin, others too. For example, Slack for Windows only works if run as admin.

So, is there anyway to turn of paranoid mode?
Or at least anywhere to check if there are any misconfigured settings that lead to this?

Comment: When you are doing your pull, where is it pulling files to? If the directory is not one you would normally have rights to, this could be why.

Comment: Try changing UAC settings.

Comment: @MrStatic: It's in a Program Files/something folder. I'm an admin of my system, I have access anywhere.

Comment: @geek1011: My UAC is set to not notify. I don't think the issues lies with this.

Comment: This is not normal, don't change your UAC settings. When using the Default (top on the slider) UAC setting, you should not get these problems. Can add the output of `whoami /all` and `icacls c:\code' to your question. Where c:\code is a location where you have problems git pulling.

Comment: Normal administrators don't have write access to files under `Program Files` you should not edit files there.

Comment: I have write access there if I RunAs the apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is a permissions issue. You have a few options. The one most would accept as proper would be to move where you are pulling the files to. Even admin accounts are treated as regular user accounts unless the program has been elevated. So I would suggest moving the files from Program Files to somewhere else. Maybe C:\ProgramData or C:\Git.

The other option is to explicitly give you account rights on the folder. Right click on the folder in question and click Properties. Then click Security and then Advanced. Add your user in and give yourself Full Control.